# Limited editing time for Django model

Tags: django, django-models, crud, user-permissions, django-2.1

My model have field with time of creation. How can I allow user to edit item only for 24 hours from created time? Also I want to make an exception from this rule for admin user.

Comment: Since you need to have the user, you have to do this in a place where you have the `request` object, i.e. in your view or form. Just show what you have tried and if you have a specific issue, show your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `save()` method of the model and check the time difference between your creation time and the current time, also if you have a relation within your model and the `User` model, you can manage the exception you want for the admin user checking if the user `is_superuser`.

edit: fix a typo

Comment: The problems with doing this in the model's `save` method are: 1. you don't have access to the `request.user` and 2. it's difficult to make this user-friendly, because `save()` is usually called after the form is shown and validated. It's much better to do this much earlier in the process and actually disable editing all-together in the view (not show a form at all). The method to actually check whether or not the model instance is editable should be a model method.

Comment: I added `is_editable(request)` method with permission logic implementation in the model and use it in overriden `ModelAdmin.change_view()`. This works fine, but also this model can be editable in related model with `TabularInline` class. So I need to add check here. There is `has_change_permission` method, but this doesn`t suite me, because it work for all related objects together, not separately.